# undefined method `highlight' Python+Pygments

Tags: python, ruby-on-rails-3, pygments

I am using `python 2.6.6` and `Pygments version 1.4` on RHEL 6 i386 but always get this error message when I try to create a new project in gitlabhq.

gem list reveals: `pygments.rb (0.2.3)`, `rubypython (0.5.1)` among others.

After running `rails s -e production` I see the following error in stdout.
This error happens first:

```
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 595ms

ActionView::Template::Error (Could not open library 'lib.so': lib.so: cannot open shared     object file: No such file or directory):
1: <% bash_lexer = Pygments::Lexer[:bash] %>
2: <div class="">
3:   <div class="git-empty">
4:     <h2>Git global setup:</h2>
app/views/projects/empty.html.erb:1:in   
`_app_views_projects_empty_html_erb___391147148_103534650'
app/controllers/projects_controller.rb:66:in `show'
```

then I see this:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `highlight' for nil:NilClass):
7: git config --global user.email  "#{current_user.email}"
8: eos
9: %>
10:     <%= raw bash_lexer.highlight(setup_str) %>
11:     <br />
12:     <br />
13:     <h2>Next steps:</h2>
app/views/projects/empty.html.erb:10:in `_app_views_projects_empty_html_erb___460979452__619384988'
app/controllers/projects_controller.rb:66:in `show'
```

Comment: Sounds more like a problem with `bash_lexer` than with `highlight()`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

linker error, fix: `yum install python-devel`